# Schwinn Racer - Frequent Punctures - Schwalbe Marathon Plus

Tags: road-bike

I'm a noob, based in Hyderabad and planning to cycle to work - atleast 2-3 times in a week (36 kms from house to work - can't do it right-away - but plan to definitely do it later, when I build up the stamina). My problem is, in Hyderabad with the Metro work going on - the roads are a disaster, my bike, which is a Schwinn Racer (Single-Speed Coaster breaks) is a great road bike, but I'm got fed-up of the frequent punctures, sometimes (5-6 in a month), I changed the tubes 2-3 times, checked tyre pressure, etc., but still the same.

I'm thinking of putting in the Schwalbe Marathon Plus tires - both front and back, do you guys think that it will be enough? Or its something to do with my bike itself? Any and all suggestions are welcome!